# Solidify thickness doesn't make sense

Tags: modifiers, units

I'm using a cylinder with cap fill type set to nothing. I usually add solidify to get the cylinder wall depth. I've been calculating it by knowing that a value of 1 completely fills in the cylinder.

However now, for no reason that I am aware of, it has started working in **two** different ways. If I open a new blender file it at least gives a predictable result. The value for thickness is the "radius" of the cylinder wall.

[image]

But on the file that I've been trying to work on it's pretty much just totally random or I'm too tired to figure out what's going on. 9.6cm=4.9mm or about 1/20th. I had set `Display > scale` to 20 but I've used solidify many times in this same way and it worked as expected (where a value of 1 fills in the cylinder). As you can see I set the scale to .05 to try and compensate but that didn't do it and I'm out of guesses.

[image]

Comment: What happens when you apply scale to the cylinder? Can you share a copy of the blend file that has the problem with https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/? maybe someone can find a setting that you have missed.

Comment: Changing the cylinder's scale works as expected but the thickness stays the same relative size. [Here's](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AiydJXfAX_8Mm3bY0T3CFqA8ZAykEMzQ/view?usp=sharing) the file (thanks for anyone willing to take a look).