# Solidify wall thickness query

Tags: geometry

I'm just starting to learn Blender so I don't know whether I'm being stupid here, but it seems to me that the Solidify modifier is counting the wall thickness twice. A wall thickness of .5m in a 1m object means no hole surely? (Blender 2.9 on a MacBook Catalina)[image: screenshot of blender 2.9 solidify]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146887

Comment: you need to apply your scale

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I looked scale up because I couldn't quite understand your comment - and then I applied scale and it was fine.